# Xcode Line Search/Dump?

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there a way to search for all the times I call a method and dump those into a text file?

Like every time I call

```
setTitle:
```

Comment: I mean in an iPHone project.

Comment: Simple search is no problem. For dumping use `grep`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to:

- Highlight the method (place the cursor within it).
- Select *Callers* from the menu available in the top-left

[image]

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for but pretty damn handy!